# How to change location of Calibre database?

Tags: linux, calibre

My files were on mounded FS /media. I have changed the location to /NAS/media and no Calibre does not see the database.

[image]

After this message nothing happens.

How to say a new location to it?

Answer (score 9):

I only know how to do it from the GUI on Mac, but it can't be too different…

Calibre Library menu > Switch/create Library…

[image]

Comment: Same on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You simply click "Ok" then a popup will open to let you select a new location for empty database or you can point to existing library location to continue using it.